# Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, environment-variables

when i write host name , password and database name in database file it works but when i acess then form env file the follwing error occurs what am i doing wrong

**Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
require('dotenv').config();
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.HOST,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'pass1',
    database: 'notetakingapp',
    multipleStatements: true
  })
  
  connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Database Connected')
  })

  module.exports = connection;




//.env

HOST:localhost
USER:root
PASSWORD:pass1
DATABASE:notetakingapp
```

Comment: Depending on the version of MySQL and your host OS, you cannot use `root` without `sudo`. You will want to give your application it’s own account with all the privileges it needs.

Comment: it was working fine but suddenly it causes an error